# Selecting and updating attribute values using Python console in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

I am working with `Landusefc` and `Class` columns (ref table).

What I want is: Selecting all water from `"Class"` and giving a value say `'8'` in the `"Landusefc"` column for these selected features.

Table looks like

[image: Test table]
I have tried the following code, it works till the selection part but doesn't seem to change the attribute value using the `ChangeAttributeValue`.

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
layer=processing.getObject('test1')
query= ' "class" = \'Water\' '
selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])

#using change Attribute to change the value of the selected feature

layer.startEditing()
for feat in selection:
     layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), 5, 8)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION 1:

You have to remove `layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])`.

Because `selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))` line gives you a `QgsFeatureIterator`, that's an iterator. When you use that iterator once, you reach the end of the iterator. Then, if you use it again, you get nothing.

In your case, when you use `selection` variable (it's an iterator now) in `[k.id() for k in selection]`, you reach the end. If you use `selection` in `for` loop, since you are at the end of the iterator, you don't have any feature now. If you want to be certain, you can add a `print("Foo")` line to `for` loop.

SOLUTION 2:

Change `for feat in selection:` into `for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():`. This solution works only on QGIS 2.x.

Comment: Thank you Kadir. this worked. Also I noticed  that we need to leave a line between start editing and the loop and then again between the loop and commit changes.