# Updating two or more fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have 5 layers:

1. NAM_USA (It has four fields of our interest, named 'bare', 'sand', 'woody' and 'built' depicting feature counts in each of the below corresponding layers.)
2. Baresoil
3. Woodyland
4. Sandbeach
5. Builtup

The process is :

1. Jump to a feature(grid) in NAM_USA using go2nextfeature plugin.
2. Calculate predefined expressions on NAM_USA fields 'bare', 'sand', 'woody' and 'built'. The calculated values are before step 3 feature counts in layers 'Baresoil', 'Sandbeach', Woodyland' and 'Builtup' respectively.
3. Make new features in layers 'Woodyland', 'Sandbeach', 'Baresoil' and 'Builtup' if any.
4. Press "go to next feature". Now, before jumping to next grid tile, the plugin AutoField will execute some expressions on rest of the fields of NAM_USA based on the calculated values of 'bare', 'sand', 'woody' and 'built' in step 2 and current values.

At present I have to calculate expression on all four fields individually in step 2.

What I want : Calculate expression on all four fields in step 2 in a single click.

Is there any method or plugin or script by which I can reduce the efforts of calculating individually?

I do not have good knowledge of PyQGIS.

Comment: one hint : rephrase your question to make it more "understandable" ...

Comment: Done!!! Kindly see!!

Comment: If you can update to QGIS 3.4, you won't have to re-calculate your fields when you update the layer. QGIS 3 has *virtual fields*, which automatically stay up to date. This feature replaced the AutoField plugin.

Comment: Virtual fields also existed in QGIS v2.x. They do not replace the plugin AutoFields. Unlike Virtual Fields, the plugin AutoFields: 1) Stores the data directly into the data source, 2) Are independent of QGIS projects, i.e., you can switch between QGIS projects and AutoFields will still work; and 3) Only work on editable vector layers.

Comment: Virtual field do not seems to be updating its value in existing features....if I make a new grid tile then it does work, which is not the case here. My work is to make features in rest of the four layers at the NAM_USA layer tile's location and update attributes in the selected tile, which is whether the feature count increased or not.

Comment: I came across this thread, could it be usefull in achieving this.....https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/318447/140271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem...
the code in go2nextfeature plugin could be modified and hence I've added a button "update" in the plugin gui.

the code for the button is added after line 343, I've added

```
def btn_update_pressed(self):

    # self.ft_pos -= 1
    self.next_ft(-1)

   {my code here}
```

but I am not sure how to write the code to calculate the expression on the fields.
some info can be found at [Selecting and updating attribute values using Python console in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318447/selecting-and-updating-attribute-values-using-python-console-in-qgis)

Comment: the expressions are like  `eval(@BARE)` for field "bare" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand your question but ... :

In **NAM_USA** u can populate your 4 fields (bare,sand, woody, built) with the following expression :

`intersecting_geom_count('bare_layer_name')`, `intersecting_geom_count('sand_layer_name')` and so on ...

Any change made in the four layers should affect the columns of your **NAM_USA** layer (after leaving the edit mode of the underlying layers and having saved the edits made + maybe a little map refresh ...)

So nothing is calculated 'manually' ...

Comment: the expression is not seems to be workin in QGIS 2.18.12. currently I have added 4 project variables like Bare_count is written as  (layer_property( 'Baresoil' , 'feature_count')). In field expression I use eval(@Bare_count) expression to get the feature counts.

Comment: mmm ... QGIS 2.18.12 maybe ... u didn't mention version in your question. i think **intersecting_geom_count** appeared in a next release of QGIS ... is the use of QGIS 2.18 mandatory for you ? What u have with your expression is a feature count **by layer** i think u're expecting a feature count **by NAM_USA feature** (or i don't understand your data structure...)

Comment: I HAVE EDITED THE QUESTION MORE SIMPLY.

Comment: Really lol ? ... u didn't answer my question : i suppose u're expecting feature count **by grid** (=NAM_USA feature) ?

Comment: `intersecting_geom_count` is part of the RefFunctions plugin, not part of any QGIS version. Install the plugin to get access to this function.

Comment: oops you're right ...

Comment: I hope now everything should be understandable!!

Comment: U still haven't answered my question about the feature count ...